# Javascript build thrown error on Storage/Preferences when run on Safari

Tags: codenameone

My Javascript build apps is running fine on any browser on Android/PC. But when come to Safari (iOS,Mac) it dies when reaching the code while trying to read data from Storage, after troubleshot and track for few days.

[image]

[image]

This happen while the apps is loading, and reading initial setup from storage, which stored after first run. (First run is ok, and after initial setup, second run hang while reach the code as shown in picture)

I have tried using both method:

```
Storage.getInstance().readObject("setup");
```

and

`String setup = Preferences.get("setup", null)`;

Both facing same problems.

Surprisingly this happening apps already working for many months with no problems, this problem just happen recently, might be Safari engine/storage updated by Apple?

I have tried to resend the Javascript build, and still facing same problem.

Below is the stack copied which break while running in Simulator using Netbeans.

```
"EDT"
at userclasses.StateMachine.postLoginForm(StateMachine.java:2412)
at generated.StateMachineBase.postShow(StateMachineBase.java:2774)
at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.postShowImpl(UIBuilder.java:2602)
at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.showForm(UIBuilder.java:2520)
at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.showForm(UIBuilder.java:2565)
at generated.StateMachineBase.startApp(StateMachineBase.java:66)
at generated.StateMachineBase.<init>(StateMachineBase.java:31)
at generated.StateMachineBase.<init>(StateMachineBase.java:118)
at userclasses.StateMachine.<init>(StateMachine.java:170)
at com.mycompany.project.wclient.CMAIN.start(CMAIN.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:123)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1152)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:969)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Please advice.

Comment: Can you provide the callstack to these calls (from the simulator just break on a breakpoint and copy the stack trace), usually that's more important than the actual call.

Comment: Can you advice how to? This problem happened only on Javascript port, on Safari (iOS/Mac) and how it relates to Simulator (JavaSE) ?  For your info, for those social iOS apps (WeChat, LINE, Facebook) which has builtin browser, this problem wont happen. Only using Safari, Chrome on iOS also facing same problem.

Comment: I tried, dont know this is the stack trace you need.. I set a break point just after the Preferences.get() , but I cant paste here.. as stackoverflow show my comment too long..

Comment: Edit your question and add the details there, then comment here so I see the change

Comment: Thanks for your help, as per guard, I edit my question by appending the stack copied from Netbeans while break after the first Preferences.get()

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting this. Looks like Safari 10 broke some things in the storage library we use (LocalForage). I have fixed the problem on the build server.  It will be available in the next build server update on Friday.

Comment: Thank you! I will resend the built on Saturday. Any way to get notified after the build server update? I would like to sent the build asap..

Comment: Problem solved! After clear all safari's history, thank you!